# Separate answer keys by chapter number

Tags: exam, books, exsheets, questionnaire

Consider this code in latex:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings-format=\large\bfseries,name=Problem]{solution}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\questionstar{\texorpdfstring{\bonusquestionsign}{* }}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\bonusquestionsign{\llap{$\bigstar$\space}}
\NewQuSolPair
{question*}[name=\questionstar Bonus Question]
{solution*}[name=\questionstar Solution]
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcounter{solcount}
\setcounter{solcount}{1}
\newcommand\CC{%
    \grayitem\label{sol:\arabic{solcount}}
    \stepcounter{solcount}
}

\newcommand\printmyanswers{%
    \section*{\centering Answers Sheet}
    
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\thequestion}{% 
        
        \noindent
        \thechapter.\x.~\ref{sol:\x}\par
    }
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\olditem\item
\newcommand{\grayitem}{\let\item\olditem\item\preto\item{\color{black}}}

\begin{document}

    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter*{Preface}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
    \chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}
    
    \begin{question}
        What is a function?
        
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item First item
                \CC Second item
                \item Fourth item
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{question}\printmyanswers

\end{document}
```

How it possible change above code to keys in answer sheet separated by chapter number like this?[image]

Comment: The thing is, you're not using the `solution` environment, so you can't just print the solutions by chapter, which is a facility `exsheets` already provides. Is there any particular reason you're rolling your own here? I'm not familiar with the package, so I don't know its limitations.

Comment: I played with this for a bit, but I think I'd redesign the setup, which is probably not what you want. I'd also be inclined to use a package designed for multiple choice questions, because there's really not much point reinventing the wheel. But, like I say, that's probably not what you want, so hopefully somebody more in tune with `exsheets` will have more to offer.

Comment: @cfr How is it possible print solution by chapter in exsheet?

Comment: There's a section on it in the manual you just pass the chapter (or section) numbers to `\printsolutions` and it produces the solutions for the relevant chapter(s) (or sections). So you could print them one at a time or whatever. But you have to set it up for that to work and you're not using `solution` at all.