# Using a new command in the custom environment

Tags: macros, environments

As you can see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings-format=\large\bfseries,name=Problem]{solution}
\usepackage{enumerate,tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\squared{\arabic*}}
\newcounter{correctchoice}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{correctchoice}{\refstepcounter{correctchoice}%
    \edef\@currentlabel{\thechapter.\thequestion~\BODY}%
    \label{correctchoice:\thehint}%
}
\newcommand\printmycorrectchoice{% you could use \foreach, but this is faster
    \bgroup% use local registers
    \count1=\value{correctchoice}% a macro would also work
    \setcounter{correctchoice}{0}%
    \loop\ifnum\value{correctchoice}<\count1
    \stepcounter{correctchoice}%
    \noindent\ref{correctchoice:\thehint}\par
    \repeat
    \egroup}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\bubble}[1]% #1 is correct choice (out of 4)
{\bgroup
    \fboxsep=0pt
    \count1=0
    \count2=#1\relax
    \loop\ifnum\count1<4
    \advance\count1 by 1
    \ifnum\count1=\count2
    \fbox{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1em}{\baselineskip}}\quad
    \else
    \fbox{\makebox[1em]{\number\count1}\strut}\quad
    \fi
    \repeat
    \egroup}
\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}
    
    \begin{question}
        Which of the following answers is correct for the given recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+n$?
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $O(n^2)$
            \item $O(n^3)$
            \item $O(n^4)$
            \item $O(n\log n)$
        \end{enumerate}
\begin{correctchoice}
    \bubble{2}
\end{correctchoice}


    \end{question}
    

    \chapter{answer Sheet}

    \printmycorrectchoice
    
    
\end{document}
```

I have a small issue that I'd like to get assistance with in fixing. When I use command \bubble in the correct choice environment, LaTeX gives me the following error:

[image]

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: Passing `\BODY` to an `\edef` is bound to fail miserably in general... especially if `\BODY` contains non-expandable content.

Comment: Unrelated but you definition of `\squared` is just an incredibly slower version of `\fbox`.

Comment: Could you guide me more?

Comment: I find `\thehint`  as component of arguments of `\label` while `\thehint` is not defined in your example. Besides this in a `\label`-command I might use `\number\value{hint}` in case `hint` is to be a LaTeX-counter.

Comment: Are you ***sure*** you want the text of the environment inside `\@currentlabel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `\thehint` is defined—perhaps it should be `\thecorrectchoice`?—you can easily do s.th. like

```latex
\NewEnviron{correctchoice}{%
  \begingroup
  \refstepcounter{correctchoice}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{%
    \thechapter\unexpanded{.}\thequestion\unexpanded{~}%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
  }%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\@currentlabel
  \label{correctchoice:\thehint}%
  \endgroup
}
```

, but that is error-prone due to `correctchoice` being an environment where the user might add additional surrounding spaces or empty lines/`\par`-tokens, or might issue the command `\bubble` in the wrong way, or might add whatsoever things to the body of the environment.

In a [comment to another question of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700158/separate-answer-keys-by-chapter-number#comment1740686_700158) you mentioned that for each chapter you wish to print solutions at the end of a chapter.

So let's resort to the infrastructure of exsheets:

```latex
% The documentclass book does not offer an option 14pt !
% The documentclass book also does not offer an option cleardoublepage=... !
% (But scrbook does, afaik.)
% \documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}
%
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{enumerate,tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{multicol} % This is not needed for the MRE/MCVE

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{namelessrunin}{default}{
  runin = true ,
  number-post-code = \space ,
  % attach = { main[l,vc]points[l,vc](\linewidth+\marginparsep,0pt) } ,
  join = {
           main[l,vc]number[l,vc](0pt,0pt)
        }
}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1], counter-within={chapter}}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam, headings-format = {\large\bfseries}, name = Problem}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{headings=namelessrunin, headings-format={\normalsize\normalfont}}

\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\squared{\arabic*}}

\newcommand*\squared[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};
  }%
}
\newcommand*\squaredblack[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=3pt, fill=black] (char) {\phantom{#1}};
  }%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \correctchoice_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bubble #1 { % #1 is the comma-list with correct answers.
  \group_begin:
  \fboxsep=0pt~
  \int_step_inline:nn {4} { % step from 1 to 4 a stepping variable which is denoted by ##1.
    \bool_set_false:N \correctchoice_bool
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { % iterate the comma-list of numbers of correct answers;
                                % ####1 in each iteration denotes the number processed
                                % in the current iteration.
      % In the n-th step iteratively compare ##1 = n to all list-elements ####1
      % and in case n = ##1 is in the list of correct answers toggle the boolean
      \int_compare:nNnT {##1} = {####1}{ \bool_set_true:N \correctchoice_bool }
    } 
    % Depending on the boolean use \square or \squareblack:
    \use:c {squared \bool_if:NT \correctchoice_bool {black} }{\number##1}
    % If not dealing with number 4, the last number, append \quad:
    \int_compare:nNnT {##1} < {4} {\quad}
  }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}

\begin{question}
Which of the following answers is correct for the given recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+n$?
\begin{enumerate}
\item $O(n^2)$
\item $O(n^3)$
\item $O(n^4)$
\item $O(n\log n)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\bubble{2}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
Which of the following answers are incorrect for the given recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+n$?
\begin{enumerate}
\item $O(n^2)$
\item $O(n^3)$
\item $O(n^4)$
\item $O(n\log n)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\bubble{1, 3,4}
\end{solution}



\chapter*{answer Sheet}
\printsolutions[chapter]

\chapter{Basic Number Theory}

\begin{question}
Which are solutions to $(x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 = (x_3)^2$?
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$, $x_3=1$
\item $x_1=3$, $x_2=4$, $x_3=5$
\item $x_1=3$, $x_2=5$, $x_3=7$
\item $x_1=5$, $x_2=12$, $x_3=13$
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\bubble{1,2 ,4}
\end{solution}


\begin{question}
Which are not solutions to $(x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 = (x_3)^2$?
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$, $x_3=1$
\item $x_1=3$, $x_2=4$, $x_3=5$
\item $x_1=3$, $x_2=5$, $x_3=7$
\item $x_1=5$, $x_2=12$, $x_3=13$
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\bubble{3}
\end{solution}

\chapter*{answer Sheet}
\printsolutions[chapter]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

In case you cannot use the environment `solution` you can define your own mechanism.

As a starting point I implemented a mechanism where the command `\correctchoices` is to occur **inside(!)** the question environment and a command `\printpendingchoices` can be used for printing the bubbles that were not printed yet.

The mechanism internally relies on `\label`-`\ref` which implies that you need to compile the code several times until everything matches out and that you need to obey warnings on the console and in the .log-file about the need of re-running LaTeX—these warnings are of pattern:
`LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`

Each instance of `\correctchoices` creates a cross-referencing-label from which via `\ref`—`\ref*` in case the package hyperref is loaded— you get
`\correctchoicesline{⟨number of the question⟩}{⟨comma-list of numbers of correct answers⟩}`.  `\printpendingchoices` does `\ref`/`\ref*` for you.

So the starting point for modifying the appearance of bubbles is the macro `\correctchoicesline` which in turn prints the ⟨*number of the question*⟩ of the question and calls `\bubble`, hereby providing ⟨*comma-list of numbers of correct answers*⟩ as `\bubble`'s argument.

```latex
% The documentclass book does not offer an option 14pt !
% The documentclass book also does not offer an option cleardoublepage=... !
% (But scrbook does, afaik.)
% \documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}
%
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{enumerate,tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{multicol} % This is not needed for the MRE/MCVE

\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1], counter-within={chapter}}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings-format=\large\bfseries,name=Problem]{solution}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\squared{\arabic*}}

\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand*\squaredblack[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=3pt, fill=black] (char) {\phantom{#1}};}}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_correctchoices_int
\int_new:N \g_printpendingchoices_intervallstart_int
\int_zero:N \g_correctchoices_int
\int_gset:Nn \g_printpendingchoices_intervallstart_int {1 + \g_correctchoices_int}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \correctchoices #1 {
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set:cpn {\tl_to_str:n{@currentlabel}} {
    \token_to_str:N \correctchoicesline{\exp_args:No\QuestionNumber{\CurrentQuestionID}}{#1}
  }
  \int_gincr:N \g_correctchoices_int
  \label{\tl_to_str:n{@choice@:}\int_to_arabic:n{ \g_correctchoices_int }}
  \group_end:
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \correctchoicesline #1#2 {%
  % #1 number of question, #2 comma list with numbers of correct answers
  \par
  \addvspace{4pt}
  \noindent#1\nobreakspace\bubble{#2}
}%
\bool_new:N \correctchoice_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bubble #1 { % #1 is the comma-list with correct answers.
  \group_begin:
  \fboxsep=0pt~
  \int_step_inline:nn {4} { % step from 1 to 4 a stepping variable which is denoted by ##1.
    \bool_set_false:N \correctchoice_bool
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { % iterate the comma-list of numbers of correct answers;
                                % ####1 in each iteration denotes the number processed
                                % in the current iteration.
      % In the n-th step iteratively compare ##1 = n to all list-elements ####1
      % and in case n = ##1 is in the list of correct answers toggle the boolean
      \int_compare:nNnT {##1} = {####1}{ \bool_set_true:N \correctchoice_bool }
    } 
    % Depending on the boolean use \square or \squareblack:
    \use:c {squared \bool_if:NT \correctchoice_bool {black} }{\number##1}
    % If not dealing with number 4, the last number, append \quad:
    \int_compare:nNnT {##1} < {4} {\quad}
  }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_new:Npn \printpendingchoices{
  \int_step_inline:nnn {\g_printpendingchoices_intervallstart_int}{\g_correctchoices_int} {
     \cs_if_exist:NTF \hyperref {\ref*} {\ref}  {\tl_to_str:n{@choice@:}\int_to_arabic:n{##1}}
  }
  \int_gset:Nn \g_printpendingchoices_intervallstart_int {1 + \g_correctchoices_int}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}

\begin{question}
Which of the following answers is correct for the given recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+n$?
\begin{enumerate}
\item $O(n^2)$
\item $O(n^3)$
\item $O(n^4)$
\item $O(n\log n)$
\end{enumerate}
\correctchoices{2}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Which of the following answers are incorrect for the given recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+n$?
\begin{enumerate}
\item $O(n^2)$
\item $O(n^3)$
\item $O(n^4)$
\item $O(n\log n)$
\end{enumerate}
\correctchoices{1, 3,4}
\end{question}

\chapter*{answer Sheet}
\printpendingchoices



\chapter{Basic Number Theory}

\begin{question}
Which are solutions to $(x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 = (x_3)^2$?
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$, $x_3=1$
\item $x_1=3$, $x_2=4$, $x_3=5$
\item $x_1=3$, $x_2=5$, $x_3=7$
\item $x_1=5$, $x_2=12$, $x_3=13$
\end{enumerate}
\correctchoices{1,2 ,4}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Which are not solutions to $(x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 = (x_3)^2$?
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$, $x_3=1$
\item $x_1=3$, $x_2=4$, $x_3=5$
\item $x_1=3$, $x_2=5$, $x_3=7$
\item $x_1=5$, $x_2=12$, $x_3=13$
\end{enumerate}
\correctchoices{3}
\end{question}

\chapter*{answer Sheet}
\printpendingchoices


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this code doesn't run at all!

Comment: @MR_  On my TeX-platform - pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 , TeX Live 2020,  LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch), L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> - this code compiles without any error-message. Exclamation mark! Probably you can tell me what the problem is? What error-messages do you get? (.log-file and console-output, i.e., the real info - not some weird pre-filtered excerpt coming from some pseudo-fancy user-interface.)

Comment: I use environment solution for other purpose, so I shouldn't use that to print bubble in that. From this argument I decide to introduce environment correctchoice, Could you according to this observation modify correctchoice to accept \buuble command? Thank you

Comment: @MR_ I added another variant which oes without solution environment. || Do you still claim that my first example doesn't run at all? If so I'd like to know about error-messages etc. In case my first example just doesn't fit your needs of not using solution-environment, that's a different issue which is not my fault as specifying all needs and requirements as precisely as possible is up to you when asking the question.

Comment: @MR_ Out of modesty not mentioning everything that is needed is not a good idea in LaTeX: Mentioning just one more need/just one more condition regarding the workflow in LaTeX can lead to having to approach the matter completely differently and thus to having to completely rewrite code. You can save yourself and your helpers this work if you mention right from the start everything what you need and everything about how things should be integrated into the intended workflow.